# Password validation in Supabase

Tags: supabase, supabase-database, supabase-js

I'm using Supabase + NextJS and I would like to password validation when users sign up to my application.  I'm using Supabase's [AuthUI component](https://github.com/supabase/auth-ui), which provides weak validation (it only enforces that a password be >6 characters), and it doesn't look like I can customize it.  [Image of AuthUI Password Validation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RQ108.png)

The solution I envision is something like:

- Keep track of the password in my own React state
  When the user click's "Sign Up"
- I validate the password and then display an error message if it doesn't meet the requirements.

The problem is, the AuthUI component doesn't accept anything like a onPasswordChange prop or a onSubmit prop.

Is there a way to "hook" into a 3rd party component like this to perform custom validation on an input?

Comment: You would just create your own UI for your Auth flow. The Auth UI is there for quick simple authentication flow.